Issue in Saving a File as PDF
I am trying to save my Mathematica home works (exercises which I have to attempt on the same provided notebook as provided by the teacher) into a full PDF file. The file contains about 100 pdf pages and whenever I try to save it as a PDF, it only saves half file or sometimes even below.
Can somebody guide what is the problem? I searched and used Export commands as well, but no success.

You did not say what you did. Did you do save as pdf?  As explained in SaveANotebookAsAPDF or something else? Which version, and which OS? Mathematica should not have problem saving 100 pages pdf file. You can try to put your notebook online and maybe then someone can try and see.

I would be surprised if File > Save as... > PDF and File > Print (using the OS's PDF writer printer) both failed.  Assuming Save as... method is the only failure case, I would whittle the document down to a couple of pages that shows the issue and report that to Tech Support.

Nasser, yes, I saved my notebook in a PDF format through saveas PDF option. Also I tried exporting the notebook through the Export command, but it is not saving the full PDF, but half.

For few pages code, it works fine.
